# Escaping a "<" in the title of :ref:`title<label>`

Tags: html, xml, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, cross-reference

I'm automatically generating reStructuredText files that are rendered by Sphinx to several formats, including HTML. The reStructuredText files sometimes contain HTML special characters such as `<` that the HTML builder fails to escape resulting in invalid HTML output. This prevents me from automating the documentation generation process forcing me to manually fix the output files. A concrete example of the problem is:

```html
<div class="line">
    <code class="docutils literal notranslate">
        <span class="pre">public</span>
    </code>
    <span class="xref std std-ref">heap(
    </span>
</div>
```

It occurs on a `heap(<)` text fragment. The output currently must be manually fixed to:

```html
<div class="line">
    <code class="docutils literal notranslate">
        <span class="pre">public</span>
    </code>
    <a class="reference internal" href="heap_1.html#heap-1">
        <span class="std std-ref">heap(&lt;)</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I cannot find in the Sphinx documentation for the HTML builder any solution for this problem. Is there any workaround? Fixing the problem in the original text is not an option (the text is source code that must compile clean; escaping characters like `<` there would break its compilation). The corresponding reStructuredText file fragment is:

```
| **Extends:**
|    ``public`` :ref:`heap(<) <heap/1>`
```

which is automatically generated from a XML file fragment:

```xml
<extends>
    <name><![CDATA[heap(<)]]></name>
    <functor><![CDATA[heap/1]]></functor>
    <scope>public</scope>
    <file><![CDATA[heap_1]]></file>
</extends>
```

Comment: Will [literal blocks](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#literal-blocks) or [code blocks](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#showing-code-examples) work for your scenario?

Comment: @StevePiercy No. In the example above, I have a parametric object named `hep(<)`. A link to the object documentation will have the object name as the text of the link. But the HTML builder chokes on the `<` character.

Comment: Can you paste a sample of your reST from which you generate the HTML? It looks like you pasted only the output of `make html` in both code samples above. Whenever I tried either paragraph, inline literal, literal block, or code-block syntax, the `<` was always HTML-encoded to `&lt;` and displays correctly.

Comment: How about escaping the `<` character in the ReST markup? Like this: `heap(\<)`.

Comment: @mzjn The `.rst` files are automatically generated. Pre-processing all generated content to escape characters that are only special for HTML output would be computationally expensive (the context here is generating documentation for all APIs of Logtalk, a programming language). Shouldn't this escaping be the task of the HTML builder itself?

Comment: @PauloMoura I find this question confusing, what is the generation order of the code fences you included? Do you generated from bottom-up, meaning XML->reST->HTML? At what point does the problematic character get included? Do you intend to include additional raw HTML at some point in the process?

Comment: @bad_coder The documentation tool generates XML files, which are converted using XSLT to reST files. Sphinx then converts the reST files into HTML files.

Comment: @PauloMoura just to make sure, 4º code fence (XML) -> XSLT generates -> 3º (reST) -> Sphinx generates -> 1º code fence (HTML). Problem is you wanted the output to be 2º code fence (HTML)?

Comment: @bad_coder Yes. `<` is **not** a special character in reST. Thus, when found by the Sphinx HTML builder, it's reasonable to expect it to be converted to `&lt;`. Same for e.g. the `&` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start by addressing the Hyperlink Targets that will be referenced, the following examples use:

> [Hyperlink Targets](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-targets) - reStructuredText Markup Specification.
>
> **Named hyperlink targets** consist of an explicit markup start (".. "), an underscore, the reference name (no trailing underscore), a colon, whitespace, and a link block:
>
> ```
> .. _hyperlink-name: link-block
> ```

Next lets look at the references themselves:

> [Cross-referencing syntax](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#cross-referencing-syntax) - Roles.
>
> (...) like in reST direct hyperlinks: **`` :role:`title <target>` ``**  will refer to target, but the link text will be title.
>
> (...)
>
> [Cross-referencing arbitrary locations](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#cross-referencing-arbitrary-locations) - Roles.
>
> **:ref:**
>
> (...) but you must give the link an explicit title, using this syntax: **`` :ref:`Link title <label-name>` ``** .

Now to the question, the following reST together with a pair of Named Hyperlink Targets previously mentioned:

```
.. _hyperlink-name:

.. _hyperlink-name2/:

| **Extends:**
|    ``private`` :ref:`some title <hyperlink-name>`


| **Extends:**
|    ``private`` :ref:`some title <hyperlink-name2/>`
```

Gives the following XML doctree targets:

```xml
<target refid="hyperlink-name"></target>
<paragraph ids="hyperlink-name" names="hyperlink-name">

<target refid="hyperlink-name2"></target>
<paragraph ids="hyperlink-name2" names="hyperlink-name2/">
```

And the following XML doctree references:

```
<line><literal>private</literal>
    <reference internal="True" refid="hyperlink-name">
        <inline classes="std std-ref">some title</inline>
    </reference>
</line>

<line><literal>private</literal>
    <reference internal="True" refid="hyperlink-name2">
        <inline classes="std std-ref">some title</inline>
    </reference>
</line>
```

From these the following HTML is generated:

```html
<p id="hyperlink-name">
<p id="hyperlink-name2">

<div class="line">
    <code class="docutils literal notranslate">
        <span class="pre">private</span>
    </code>
    <a class="reference internal" href="#hyperlink-name">
        <span class="std std-ref">some title</span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="line">
    <code class="docutils literal notranslate">
        <span class="pre">private</span>
    </code>
    <a class="reference internal" href="#hyperlink-name2">
        <span class="std std-ref">some title</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

So far only the forward slash in the [`refid`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/doctree.html#refid) corresponding to `.. _hyperlink-name2/:` has been normalized. Looking at the syntax `` :ref:`Link title <label-name>` ``  this addresses any problems with the `label-name`.

Now lets try the full example:

```
| **Extends:**
|    ``private`` :ref:`heap(<) <hyperlink-name2/>`
```

The above immediatly has Sphinx issue a warning:

> C:\path_to_your_rest_file.rst:98: WARNING: undefined label: ) <hyperlink-name2/
>
> build succeeded, 1 warning.

Look carefully at the warning...! That's why your HTML was broken, because you violated one of the few syntax rules in writing the Sphinx `:ref:` role. It's not a HTML builder problem, nor a reST parser problem. The first `<` "Less-than sign" character defines the end of the `Link title` in the `:ref:` role and the beginning of the `label-name`. That's why the undefined label is `) <hyperlink-name2/` instead of just `hyperlink-name2/`.

If you escape the `<` "Less-than sign" character:

```
| **Extends:**
|    ``private`` :ref:`heap(\<) <hyperlink-name2/>`
```

In the doctree the Sphinx parser will already have converted the character to `(&lt;)`.

```xml
<line><literal>private</literal>
    <reference internal="True" refid="hyperlink-name2">
        <inline classes="std std-ref">heap(&lt;)</inline>
    </reference>
</line>
```

Also after the HTML builder step:

```html
<div class="line">
    <code class="docutils literal notranslate">
        <span class="pre">private</span>
    </code>
    <a class="reference internal" href="#hyperlink-name2">
        <span class="std std-ref">heap(&lt;)</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

> I cannot find in the Sphinx documentation for the HTML builder any solution for this problem.

There isn't any, not in [docutils configurations](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html) nor in [Sphinx configuration](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html). Because neither has a configuration to solve malformed reST or Sphinx roles.

> Fixing the problem in the original text is not an option (the text is source code that must compile clean; escaping characters like < there would break its compilation).

You don't have to change the original source code. If you're generating `XML -> XSLT -> reST` the final reST/Sphinx syntax has to be correct. So rewrite the XSLT or the XML for the `:ref:` role (or do some pre-processing on the reST before generating with Sphinx).

Comment: The suggested solution is the solution I implemented back in 2019: https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/commit/470bc7ac22b271ed35f4eab3e461770d3b1dd80c#diff-396187135e8170eb92ca4a9a1c76110674f70ddbc71792b684282f19893711df As you make clear, this is **not** an HTML builder bug as although `<` is not a special character in general in reST, it’s a special character in the particular case of xref roles.